# Replace/Update column value from text document in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I got a question on how can i update an specific column value from a row in a text document in bash.
 So far I do this:
In this case I'm trying to update the 4th column in a line from an specific account number. take the current value, sum with a new value inserted by the user and then replace that current value with the result.

Open the script with two variable $1 holds the account I ll be looking for while $2 the file name.

The text document has information like this:

```
11101   :   CAJA GENERAL            :   111     :   0
11102   :   CAJA CHICA              :   111     :   0
112     :   BANCOS                  :   11      :   0
11201   :   CUENTAS CORRIENTES      :   112     :   0
1120101 :   Banco Agrícola S.A.     :   11201   :   20
1120102 :   Banco Hipotecario S.A.  :   11201   :   0
11202   :   CUENTAS DE AHORRO       :   112     :   0
1120201 :   Banco Agrícola S.A.     :   11202   :   0
```

I use this code to find the correct row and assign the current value to the var "act" and aggregate it with another new value

```
read -p "Inserte monto" insert
    act=$(grep -w "^$1" $2  | cut -d":" -f4)
    vare=$(($act + $insert))
```

But then I need to place this new value to the exact column/row I took the original value.

How do i exactly do it? I'm quite exhausted from a long day of traveling and now I want to finish this and go to bed. Anyone could give me an idea or solution? I'd really appreciate any help right now.

EDIT:
Ok.. I went and try AWK.
Found this to "replace" text

```
awk -F':' -vOFS=' '  '{ $4 = "$vare"}1'
```

So far... once I enter that line the execution of the script stops.. or I dont know what but it doesn't continue anymore, nor shows any error.
Am I doing anything wrong?

EDIT 2:
Expected Input.
After a successful update I want the selected account to have the updated value in a existing document in my directory, the solutions so far allow me to see the updates within terminal, but is the original document the one I need to see the changes. Thanks Ed Morton for the tip

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`.

Comment: I think you should provide a file to your awk line... it is not defined what to "awk"

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Maybe try awk:

$ cat file
11101   :   CAJA GENERAL            :   111     :   0
11102   :   CAJA CHICA              :   111     :   0
112     :   BANCOS                  :   11      :   1
11201   :   CUENTAS CORRIENTES      :   112     :   0
1120101 :   Banco Agrícola S.A.     :   11201   :   20
1120102 :   Banco Hipotecario S.A.  :   11201   :   0
11202   :   CUENTAS DE AHORRO       :   112     :   0
1120201 :   Banco Agrícola S.A.     :   11202   :   0

$ insert=10

$ ident=112

$ awk -i inplace -F: "/^$ident /{gsub(/([0-9]+)$/, \$4+ $insert)};{print}" file
```

-or-

```
$ awk -i inplace -v ident="$ident" -v insert="$insert" '$1==ident{sub(/[0-9]+$/, $NF+insert)} 1' file

$ cat file
11101   :   CAJA GENERAL            :   111     :   0
11102   :   CAJA CHICA              :   111     :   0
112     :   BANCOS                  :   11      :   11
11201   :   CUENTAS CORRIENTES      :   112     :   0
1120101 :   Banco Agrícola S.A.     :   11201   :   20
1120102 :   Banco Hipotecario S.A.  :   11201   :   0
11202   :   CUENTAS DE AHORRO       :   112     :   0
1120201 :   Banco Agrícola S.A.     :   11202   :   0
```

Comment: Never enclose a script in double quotes, always single. Also see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24. `awk -v ident="$ident" -v insert="$insert" '$1==ident{sub(/[0-9]+$/, $NF+insert)} 1' file`

Comment: I see this works pretty well. But... when I try it on an existing document, nothing happens. My terminal display the data with the changes but the original document remain intact and unchanged.

Comment: nvm, I trasfered the content of the original file, to a temporal, then moved it back and it worked. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @EdMorton thx. I did not know how to place variable as search pattern

Comment: "-i inplace" is some kind of extension to awk. If it is not working, probably you have older awk version. Solution with tmp file is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sed:

```
id=$1
sed -i "/^$id *:/ s/[0-9]\+$/$vare/"  $2
```